# Rendering slowly after hiding a control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm encountering a new phenomenon (I've never seen it before), after hiding a control and switching tab it moves super slow and some times I can even see the hole the hidden control left on the same spot in the different tab. 
and even pop up a file dialog take a very long time after the operation.
(I've seen similar question not exact and none of the solutions seems to work in my case)
*) the controls I'm hiding are simply in a group-box container no data grid or such.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a small example program? No one can test this behavior as it might be because of other code.

Comment: It's hard to say what could be the problem since you showed about 0 lines of your code. Try to suspend layout on form with `this.SuspendLayout();`, hide control and then resume layout with `this.ResumeLayout();`. Also, you could, after hiding, call `Application.DoEvents();`